# How do I respond with a request header in AWS API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have a POST request coming in with a header that I need to play back with the response (Example: "Validation: 123").

The integration returns synchronously, immediately.

The header is entirely non-functional and so doesn't need to be passed through to my integration. It just needs to be passed back with the response to the inbound request.

I am trying to do this by mapping the headers from the method request through to the method response, or via the integration request/response.

For example, I'd like to set the header mapping for the integration response to `method.request.header.Validation` (ie, identically to the integration request mapping). However, this is disallowed.

Is this the right approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a limitation of AWS API Gateway.